# AngularJS: angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am calling a back-end service using angularJS to upload multipart file I am encountering an error. the response comes to my service but from there I cannot get the response to my angular controller due to the above promise error.

fileUploadService:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('module')
    .factory('FileUpload', FileUpload);

FileUpload.$inject = ['$http'];

function FileUpload($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();    
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(response){
        })
        .error(function(error){
        });
    }
        return this;
}
})();
```

controller.js:

```
        $scope.onFilesSelected = function(files) {

       var uploadUrl = "/api//customer/logo";

       FileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(files[0], uploadUrl).then(
           function(result){
               var logo =  FileUpload.getResponse();
               vm.setLogo(logo);
              // $scope.errors = FileUpload.getResponse();
           }, function(error) {
                alert('error');
           });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `uploadFileToUrl()` function has no return statement so it returns `undefined`. I guess you meant to return the promise returned by `$http`:

```
this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl) {
    var fd = new FormData();    
    fd.append('file', file);
    // Notice the return statement below
    return $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(response){
    })
    .error(function(error){
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't return any values. So do return response inside the success  and error callback as below

```
.success(function(response){
return response;
    })
.error(function(error){
return error
    });
```